# How to restrict access to my subversion server (i.e. svnserve) by IP address, so only my IP can checkout, commit, etc.?

Tags: security, svn, whitelist

I'm using Ubuntu and I have my subversion server running as you can see below:

```
root     31422     1  0 06:45 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/svnserve -d -r /var/svn/repos --log-file=/var/log/svnserve.log
```

I want to whitelist my subversion server, in other words, I want to allow only my IP address to checkout, commit, log, etc. Does svnserve support that?

**NOTE:** I'm not using Apache to access my subversion.

Comment: Configure the firewall to only allow your IP to access port 3690.

Answer (score 0):

svnserve listens on TCP port 3690 by default, so you can use any firewalling solution the restrict access to this port. For example with iptables:

```
# Let the internal network access it
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/8 -p tcp --dport 3690 -j ACCEPT
# Let a specific external IP access it
iptables -A INPUT -s 1.1.1.1 -p tcp --dport 3690 -j ACCEPT
# Drop all the rest
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3690 -j DROP
```

It would however be better security-wise if you would switch to apache + dav_svn as you get SSL encryption and user authentication and it's not too complicated to setup: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html